# Decrypted RSA result not matching the signed message

Tags: java, rsa, bouncycastle, encryption

I used Bouncy Castle Crypto APIs to decrypt a cipher text, and verify the signed message.

The signed message:

```
signedMessageOther: D0F39F8C8495CA83D2F24536083CCB280CD3A54B
```

The message decrypted:

```
01FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF003021300906052B0E03021A05000414D0F39F8C8495CA83D2F2453608
3CCB280CD3A54B
```

**Only the last 20 bytes match the** `signedMessageOther`.
**Why?**

---

Here is something about the key:

```
Algorithm: RSA
Format: X.509
Key Length: 162
```

The key is 162 bytes -1024 bi, so it is a vaild key.
Here is the code:

```
import java.security.PublicKey; 
import java.security.Security; 
import javax.crypto.Cipher; 

public class DecyrptTest { 
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception { 
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider()); 
        //msg is some secret msg ,i have deleted. 
        String msg = ""; 
        byte[] signedMsgBytes = SHA1.sign(msg); 
        String signedMessageOther=StringTools.bytesToHex(signedMsgBytes); 
        System.out.println("signedMessageOther: "+signedMessageOther); 

        String ct="1386cfed01490b9026903722324f80f8a56cc38169b46e15154ce9e7168ff589282855002e195a0c1a96d5fe540a7fa97b01ae24f365f39302e0c1186ee9308d6b94526741f7093dc2678c713bb2b1a8a6942decb35b16725353da523417cb835cea903485b19b63c2c444c8bc6c865ea78c749f10ca70b266f6078192f5c76c"; 

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA", "BC"); 
        PublicKey pubKey = KeyUtil.getPubKeyFromFile("res/key.pub"); 
        System.out.println("Algorithm: "+pubKey.getAlgorithm()); 
        System.out.println("Format: "+pubKey.getFormat()); 
        System.out.println("Key Length: "+pubKey.getEncoded().length); 

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pubKey); 
        byte[] ctBytes=StringTools.hexStringToByteArray(ct); 
        System.out.println(ctBytes.length); 
        byte[] cipherText2 = cipher.doFinal(ctBytes); 
        System.out.println("cipher: " + StringTools.bytesToHex(cipherText2)); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are are trying to drive to work with an internal combustion engine. You need a car.

RSA is a primitive operation that can be pieced with other things to make a useful encryption system. You can't just use it by itself to do the whole job.

I'm not sure if that's really saying the key is 162 bits, but if so, that's a completely useless RSA key size. An RSA key has to be at least 384 bits to be of any use at all. Also, RSA can't sign or encrypt data larger than the key. 162 bits is about 20 bytes. Sound familiar?

You can't use an engine to drive to work. You need a car. RSA is an engine.

Comment: Actually, you now have a very different problem. You're trying to run an electric car on gasoline. You need to use a `Signature`, not a `Cipher`. Search for [Digital Signatures](http://www.mobilefish.com/developer/bouncycastle/bouncycastle.html) on this link.

Comment: I hava resolved problem using a Signatuer . The signature is sha1_rsa . I also want to know other steps been done with Signatuer.